# How to export Flowbite React theme (JSON) from Figma

Tags: reactjs, themes, tailwind-css, figma, flowbite

I've put up a [Flowbite React](https://www.flowbite-react.com/) application (Flowbite a set of components styled with TailwindCSS classes).
Our UI/UX designer has created some examples/libraries in the [Figma](https://www.figma.com/) design system (based on the Flowbite components).

Flowbite's Docs say that it is easely customizable/designable in Figma etc. But I haven't found anything sepcific saying anything about Flowbite React's integration with the Figma system.

AFAIK I need a component theme configuration (in JSON format) to apply our customizations made in Figma. Something like this:

```js
const flowbiteTheme: ThemeInterface = {
  sidebar: {
    root: {
      base: "flex fixed top-0 left-0 z-20 flex-col flex-shrink-0 pt-16 h-full duration-75 border-gray-200 lg:flex transition-width dark:border-gray-700 w-64 dark",
    }
  }
};
```

What is good way way to get the style customizations from Figma into Flowbite React.

I've tryed Figma's [Clapy plugin](https://www.figma.com/community/plugin/1083031796594968801/Clapy---Export-Figma-design-to-code-(React%2C-HTML%2C-CSS)), but it's export doesn't even have any files about Tailwind or Flowbite (although the components do look like they have Flowbite style's on them).

Am I missing something from the process or just using a wrong plugin in Figma or what?

Answer (score 1):

try to use Figma Dev mode.
Here is the doc - https://www.figma.com/dev-mode/